# Can one attain Moksha just by Guru / matru / pitru bhakti?

Tags: krishna, moksha, guru, bhakti, parents

Can one attain Moksha just by Guru Bhakti and not following the methods of Nava vidha Bhakti? I have known the story of Pundarikan who had ardent devotion for his Parents. Was he blessed with Moksha by Panduranga? What does the scriptures say about Guru/matru and pitru bhakti

Comment: Guru is the sacchidananda so that seems true

Comment: Yeah You mean to say it helps us attain Moksha? and references from Vedic texts?

Comment: Girish Chandra gosh did bhakti to Shri Ramakrishna(his guru) and he got liberated

Comment: Oh It would be great if you post it as an answer rather than a comment!